# iOS: NSNumberFormatter with Swedish Format replace comma With space

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I was trying to formate double values to currencies formats with the following code snippet

```
+(NSString *)formatAmountToCurrency:(double)amount{

    NSLocale *priceLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sv-SE"] ;
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *negFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",formatter.positiveFormat];
    [formatter setNegativeFormat:negFormat];
    [[PropertyManager sharedPropertyManager]setCurrencyFormatter:formatter];

    [formatter setLocale:priceLocale];
    NSString * priceString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(amount)];

    return priceString;
}
```

The problem is .. it's working on formats like US dollar and Euro and even danish kroner .. but when using sv-SE which is formate for Swedish it gives space instead of dot group separator.. 
For Example
1900.50 will be (1 900,50 Kr).. while it should be (1.900,50).. it's removing the dot and replacing it with space

Any idea will be appreciated .

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't that the default Swedish number format?

Comment: no the default should be 1.900,00 .. it replace the dot with space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched and the swedish currency format is # ###,## (http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat) - with the space.

Anyway, you are returning a string, you can replace what you don't want, see:

```
+(NSString *)formatAmountToCurrency:(double)amount{

    [...]

    NSString * priceString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(amount)];

    priceString = [priceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" Kr" withString:@""];
    priceString = [priceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"."];

    return priceString;
}
```

I know, it's an ugly solution, but it works for now.

Comment: seriously.. that's stupid format .. totally .. anyway this is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setGroupingSeparator` like so:

```
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
```